# How to set custom boot logo On Samsung a52?

Tags: samsung, customization

I want to set custom boot logo (Not boot animation) on Samsung A52 (SM-A525F) powered with Qualcomm Snapdragon. There's no logo.bin or splash.bin in my official firmware.

Answer (score 0):

That would most certainly require rooting the phone to get started.

Be noted that rooting the device and messing with the OS could have certain implications like your device failing to pass the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview) checks. This new API is used by developers and manufacturers to determine if your device is trustworthy and unmodified, which is always a good thing.

As an Android developer I advice **against rooting** the phone or messing with the OS in general, and specially not for changing a screen you probably haven't seen in months.